# Sharing Folders for Users Sharing the Same Computer

Tags: permissions, samba, users

I have 4 users including myself which are in a specific groups. I also want to create 4 folders labeled Directors, Managers, General-Staff and Company-Wide.

jack is in the "Directors" group

Russel is in the "Managers" group

And Barry is in the "G-Staff" group

I want each group to have different permissions to each of these folders and don't know how. I also don't know how to share the folders among all users on the computer either.

This is for a college assignment and I would really appreciate some advice on how to create a folder that all users can see in their home directory and for those folders to be accessible depending the what that group is allowed to do to those folders. e.g. Barry can only read the "company-wide" folder as Russel has rwx permissions.

I am not in either of these three groups my self

thank you.

Comment: I would create the folders in `/opt` with `mkdir` (as root), then change the permissions to allow certain groups with `chown` and `chmod`, and then make symbolic links to the folders in the users' home directories with `ln`.

Comment: @pomsky OK. Thank you, I wish that high-rep people could just convert comments to answers so we don't have to go through this so many times on SE.

Answer (score 1):

I would create the folders in `/opt` with `mkdir` (as root), then change the permissions to allow certain groups with `chown` and `chmod`, and then make symbolic links to the folders in the users' home directories with `ln`.